# What does "System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set." mean?

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
'FILL THE PRODUCT COMBO BOX

Private Sub FillProducts()
    Dim NRec As Integer
    Call SetStateP("View")  'error code
    cboProducts.Items.Clear()
    If ProductsTable.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        For NRec = 0 To ProductsTable.Rows.Count - 1
            cboProducts.Items.Add(ProductListing(ProductsTable.Rows(NRec).Item("ProductID").ToString, ProductsTable.Rows(NRec).Item("Description").ToString, ProductsTable.Rows(NRec).Item("Price").ToString))
        Next NRec
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what it says. If you have bound a data source to the control then you cannot add or remove items directly via the `Items` collection. The control reflects what's in the data source so any changes need to be made to that data source. You can either modify what's in the existing data source or you can bind a new data source.

You haven't shown us how you bound the control in the first place, so it's hard to be more specific than that. Based on what I see in your code, I'm guessing that you have populated a `DataTable` and bound that, either directly or via a `BindingSource`. In that case, you need to either modify the contents of that `DataTable`, e.g. clear and repopulate it, or else populate a new `DataTable` and bind that in its place. I'd recommend the former.

Comment: 'bind combobox 
        cboProducts.DataSource = ProductsTable
        cboProducts.DisplayMember = "Description"
        cboProducts.ValueMember = "ProductID"
        txtProductID.DataBindings.Add("Text", ProductsTable, "ProductID")
        txtDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", ProductsTable, "Description")
        txtPrice.DataBindings.Add("Text", ProductsTable, "Price")
        txtNumberSold.DataBindings.Add("Text", ProductsTable, "NumberSold")
        'establish currency manager for Products
        ProductsManager = DirectCast(Me.BindingContext(ProductsTable), CurrencyManager)

Comment: @PcRomanofsky, a big wad of unformatted code in a comment on an answer is useless. No one should have to read the comments on the question to understand the question, never mind comments on an answer. Edit your question and provide all the relevant information there. Format the code properly so it can be read easily. Also, provide an actual explanation of the problem in the question too. Nothing but code in the question is a bad question. Provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question properly.